# Elasticsearch Request cannot be executed; I/O reactor status: STOPPED

Tags: elasticsearch

We are getting the below error while executing the search requests. We are using ElasticSearch 7.9.2v

java.lang.RuntimeException: Request cannot be executed; I/O reactor status: STOPPED
I am only using sync method to execute the requests as shown below:

`client.search(searchRequest,RequestOptions.DEFAULT)`
When the first time the issue occurs looks like it stops the RestHighLevelClient and the subsequent calls are getting failed with the same error. we need to restart our app to initialize the client again. From last two days, we are running into this issue very frequently.

Note: we are not closing the client for every call. We initiate the client during application startup and close it only when the app is getting shut down.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. It was caused by OutOfMemoryError that was caused by other changes at my service.

So increasing heap-space limit helped.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the java process (in my case is SpringBoot java process) fixes the problem.